# Ajax success: {return false;}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to return `false` from `$.ajax` when `success` is complete:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '' + $website_url + 'queries/voorraad_berekenen.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        aantal: $(this).parent('form').children('.quantity').val(),
        item_number_1: $(this).parent('form').children('.item_number_1').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This doesn't work. Is there a work around?

Comment: You mean you want to return false from `$.ajax` when success is complete?

Comment: Yes, between the success function there is a script thats checks several variables, and based on that i want to return false;

Comment: You need to research [callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549658/jquery-ajax-how-do-callbacks-work). There are a **lot** of questions about this.

Comment: Please show us the code that is supposed to read the return value. That way it will be much easier to provide a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: You are returning `false` to the caller of that function which is jQuery internals and they don't really use the return value for anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your post I guess that you call a function that contains the `$.ajax()` and try to `return false` to that function. but you can't do that such way, because **AJAX** is asynchronous.

It's better to call a function from the ajax success function like following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '' + $website_url + 'queries/voorraad_berekenen.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        aantal: $(this).parent('form').children('.quantity').val(),
        item_number_1: $(this).parent('form').children('.item_number_1').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
        var returned = true;
        if(some_condition_not_satisfied) {
          returned = false;
        } else {

        }
        // call a function
        calledFromAjaxSuccess(returned);
    }
});

function calledFromAjaxSuccess(result) {
  if(result) {
    alert('TRUE');
  } else {
    alert('FALSE');
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing i want is that the form (paypal form in this case) doesn't execute the post to paypal's paymend page when the quantity is less then the product stock, and when it is a number. Maybe someone has a better idea to use within the success function. Something like abborting the form submition

Comment: @thecodeparadox: Even making the AJAX call `async: false` doesn't allow me to `return false;` in the `success` function. I created a separate function which returns false and called it in the `success` function to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: This is basically the explanation to the answer of @thecodeparadox.
http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this (values 1 and 0 should be changed to the ones that you use):

```
success: function(result){
if(result === '1'){
// do something
}
else
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, The problem is, it just never works when the "return false;" is between the "success: function" Otherwise it already would have worked

Comment: It still does not make sense to `return` here.

Answer (score 0):

just use asunc false it can work fine i have implemented like that only

just try it

```
$.ajax({
    url: '' + $website_url + 'queries/voorraad_berekenen.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        aantal: $(this).parent('form').children('.quantity').val(),
        item_number_1: $(this).parent('form').children('.item_number_1').val()
    },
   async: false, //=>>>>>>>>>>> here >>>>>>>>>>>
    success: function(result) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

it is working fine try it once

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="yourpage" method="post" onsubmit="return matchpass();">
  <div>
   <label> Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label> Email ID</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email">            
  </div>
  <div>
   <label> Mobile No</label>
   <input type="text" name="mob"  maxlength="10" onkeyup="check_if_exists();" autocomplete="off" id="mob">
  </div>                             
  <div>
   <button type="button" >Send</button>
  </div>
  <span id="err"></span>
  <div>
   <label> OTP</label>
   <input type="password" name="otp" id="otp"  maxlength="6" placeholder="****">
   <span id="err2"></span>
  </div>    
  <div>
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset-btn">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >              
  </div>
</form>
<input type="hidden"  id="otpcheck"/>



<script>
function matchpass()
{

     $.ajax({   
    type:"post",
    url: "yourpage",
    data:{ mobile:mob,otp:otp},
    success:function(data)
    {
       if(data==1)
       {
           document.getElementById("otpcheck").value=1; //important
       }else{

           document.getElementById("err2").style.color = "red";
           document.getElementById("err2").innerHTML = "invalid OTP Number ";
         document.getElementById("otpcheck").value=0; //important
       }


    }
    });

    if(document.getElementById("otpcheck").value==0){
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I face this problem. then i found the actual solution. use async : false, inside ajax call

```
function thisisavailavailusername(uname){
var dataString = 'username='+ uname.value;
var trueorfalse = false;
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/BloodBook/checkavailableusername",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    async : false, //user this then everything ok
    success: function(html){
        if(html=="true"){
            $('#validusername').html('Available');
            trueorfalse = true;
        }else{
            $('#validusername').html('Not Available');
            trueorfalse = false;
        }

    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Something Wrong...");
    }
});

return trueorfalse;
```

}