# ajax always return true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
function lks()
        {  
            var groupname = document.getElementById('groupname').value;
            $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'checkgroupname.php?groupname='+groupname,
                type: 'get',
                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                    return false;
                }                    
            });

        }
```

I have above code for ajax and it goes to always true condition even if I return false; Please help me to sortout this problem

here is checkgroupname.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$loginuser = $_SESSION['username'];
$groupname = $_GET['groupname'];
$checkgroupname = trim(`sudo grep -w $groupname /home/$loginuser/.groupmanagement`);
if($checkgroupname!=NULL){
    echo json_encode("already");
}
else{
    echo json_encode("allow");
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us your `checkgroupname.php` code.

Comment: are you showing the result in aler?

Comment: Show back end code..

Comment: @lokesh AJAX is asynchronous. so you need to call function

Comment: the `return false` in the success callback is meaningless

Comment: Actually below is my code

Comment: @LOKESH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767128/ajax-success-return-false

Comment: function `lks` will always return `undefined`

Comment: You can't return from an async function

Comment: So what is solution for that

Comment: I have to check groupname is already used or not for that purpose I have written this code

Comment: How / where / when in your code do you trigger the `lks()` function?

Comment: onclick of submit button

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="creategroup" value="Submit" onclick="return lks();" title="Click here to create users">Submit</button>

Comment: do you check your php file separately? did it work correct?

Comment: @Alireza Separate php file is also working fine.

Comment: Rename success data from result to some other name. Because there is a predefined variable called result is available in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you use `return false` to return the value.

I think, you should use to return data using `echo`.

```
$data = ['returnValue'=> 'true'];
echo json_encode($data);
exit(); //exit the execution further
```

In Ajax success

```
console.log(result);
```

FYI, please make sure that your server side condition / code is working properly.